# Can rviz visualize custom msgs?

Tags: rviz, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm running ros indigo. I have a topic publishing a customized ros msgs which includes sensor data and the position information. For example, I have the temperature data regarding the position data, how to have something maybe like a 3D plot to visualize the data in rviz?

Thank you so very much for any kind of help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/298271/can-rviz-visualize-custom-msgs?/) by [KyleUVA](https://answers.ros.org/users/36605/kyleuva/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-07-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In general the answer would be: no, not without you writing an RViz plugin for your custom message.

> For example, I have the temperature data regarding the position data [..]

In this example though: [sensor_msgs/Temperature](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Temperature.html) includes a `header` field, which includes a `frame_id` field. If you set that to the name of a TF frame and the TF frame origin (ie: its current position) corresponds to the 'position data' that you mention, then I believe the `Temperature` display should be able to visualise it 'in place'.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KyleUVA](https://answers.ros.org/users/36605/kyleuva/) on 2018-07-26**:
Thank you gvdhoorn! Moving TF frame is not what I want. I would like to start with create a rviz plugin for my custom msgs. I've checked many tutorial or blogs about it in c++ but I'm still confused. Do you have recommended resources? BTW, do you know if I can write a plugin in python or not?